# Array sorting in VBNET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have two dimensional integer `array x, y` as below

```
{1160, 0}, 
{1560, 400}, 
{11940, 10380}, 
{12480, 540},
{12540, 60},
{12600, 60},
{12720, 120},
{13120, 400},
{13380, 260},
{13680, 300},
{14000, 320}
```

I need to pick `{13120, 400}`. I arrive at this by walking the `x` values in descending order and taking the first pair where the `y` value increases from the previous record.

Comment: What have you tried so far, code-wise?

Comment: Are you saying that {13120, 400} beats {11940, 10380} because there are two items with y=400 and there is only one item with y=10380?

Comment: I agree with @AndrewMorton I am a little confused why that item is the one which gets picked - Can you explain how you've reached that conclusion?

Comment: Since the x value is highest when compare to other with y value.. so i come to that decision

Comment: {13120, 400} beats {11940, 10380} because x value 13120 is greater than 11940

Comment: Why, then, does {13120, 400} beat {14000, 320}?  You need to be able to write clear rules that describe how the items should be ordered.

Comment: How is the relationship between X and Y determined? If it's X+Y, then (11940,10380) is higher. If it's X-Y, then (14000,320) is first. If it's X/Y, then (12600,60) or (1160,0) wins If it's just X, and then only look at Y as a tie-breaker, then (14000,320) wins. We need a simple formula in terms if X and Y that produce a number used for sorting. What you've provided so far looks ambiguous and arbitrary.

Comment: Y column is previous X value - Current X value. (14000,320) wont come first because Y value is greater in {13120, 400} and also (11940,10380) wont come because X value greater in  {13120, 400}

Comment: So give me a formula in terms of X and Y that, when applied to the sample data, produces the greatest result for the 13120,400 pairing. 13210,400 still seems arbitrary.  By your own rules, 13120 still shouldn't come first, because it's _neither_ highest x or highest y. It might be pretty good in both, but going at something fuzzy like "pretty good" is a problem for computers. You need to clarify how that is determined.

Comment: Right now, the best I can come up with is to sort the pairs by X value in descending order, and take the first pair where the Y value increases from the previous item.

Comment: you are right.. i am also finding in that way.. {11940,10746}. {13120, 400} is what i got... after that we need to check which x value is greater between two... so 13120 is the result.

Comment: In that principle, another 2d array {11980,10620}. {14800,940},{13020,660}, {1000,540},{15040,180},{13720,140}... Answer is {14800,940}

Comment: Hey, progress! :) Now... what version of Visual Studio are you using? Because there are somethings I can do in the more recent version to make this easier.

Comment: i am using vs 2013

Comment: Okay, so Tuples are out, then. `List(Of Integer())` it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function GetLargestPair(ByVal data(,) As Integer) As Integer()

    'First convert to data structure that's easier to use
    Dim records As New List(Of Integer())
    For i As Integer = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
        records.Add(New Integer() {data(i, 0), data(i, 1)})
    Next i

    'Now it's very easy to sort descending by the X values:
    Dim sorted = records.OrderByDescending(Function(r) r(0)).ThenBy(Function(r) r(1))

    'And then use that to find the result
    Dim PrevY As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
    For Each pair As Integer() In sorted
        If pair(1) > PrevY Then Return pair
        PrevY = pair(1)
    Next
    'Not clear what you want in this case. I just returned the overall largest X,
    ' but you might prefer Nothing or throwing an exception
    Return sorted.First()
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
'Sample data
Dim data = {{1160, 0}, {1560, 400}, {11940, 10380}, {12480, 540}, {12540, 60}, {12600, 60}, {12720, 120}, {13120, 400}, {13380, 260}, {13680, 300}, {14000, 320}}

Dim result = GetLargestPair(data)
'result should now contain {13120, 400}
```

Comment: You are right... can you sample this data

 Dim data = {{22380, 8380}, {22540, 160}, {22640, 100}, {22700, 60}, {22760, 60}, {22760, 0}, {22760, 0}, {22740, -20}, {22720, -20}, {22720, 0}, {22500, -220}, {22500, 0}, {22520, 20}, {22520, 0}, {22520, 0}, {22540, 20}, {22620, 80}, {24840, 2220}, {24940, 100}, {25060, 120}, {25220, 160}, {25340, 120}, {25420, 80}, {25500, 80}, {25500, 0}, {25460, -40}, {25420, -40}, {25320, -100}, {25120, -200}, {25020, -100}}

Answer will be {25500, 80}

Comment: oh yes.. it results  {25420, 80} where as {25500, 80} is greater with x value with same y value.. how to deal with this?

Comment: Check it again. The addition from the previous comment fixed this.

Comment: Yes.. i found another sample data 
Dim data = {{40, 0}, {140, 100}, {260, 120}, {460, 200}, {1000, 540}, {1360, 360}, {11980, 10620}, {12360, 380}, {13020, 660}, {13260, 240}, {13460, 200}, {13580, 120}, {13720, 140}, {13780, 60}, {13820, 40}, {13860, 40}, {14800, 940}, {14800, 0}, {14820, 20}, {14860, 40}, {15040, 180}, {15180, 140}, {15340, 160}}

Answer is {14800,940) but it gives {15040,180} since 940 is greater than 180

Comment: 14800 is no longer part of the "largest X" group, based on the previous rules. If it matters because the Y is much larger, then (11980, 10620) should matter more.